# Implementing canplaythrough in SoundManager2

Tags: javascript, algorithm, html, soundmanager2

I need help making an algorithm to detect that all the conditions for [HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#dom-media-have_enough_data) are met (and continuously checking until they are met) and I am stumped as to how to calculate all the necessary variables using SoundManager2's `whileloading` option. I don't need code, just a general algorithm that would work (even pseudo-code is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that setting the `whileplaying` option is a more optimal and simple solution. This is my whileplaying solution:

```
function () {
 aSound.options.whileplaying = null;
 if (paused) {
  aSound.stop();
 }
 onCanPlayThrough_callback_here();
}
```